# Implementing a functional interface via method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator, functional-interface

First I got a class named after my Chinese name

```
public class Yxj<T> {
    private T[] data;
    private int size = 0;
    private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;
    public Yxj(Comparator<? super T> c) {
        data= (T[]) new Object[16];
        comparator = c;
    }

    public void addItem(T t){
        data[size++] = t;
    }

    public int sort(){
        return comparator.compare(data[0], data[1]);
    }


    public  T[] getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

in which a `Comparator` resides,then I defined a `Norwich` keeping a field `order` and setter and getter of it, finally there's a method used to implement the `compare(T t1,T t2)` in `Comparator`.

```
public class Norwich {
    private int order;


    public Norwich(int o) {
        order = o;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }


    public int compareOrder(Norwich n) {
        if (order > n.getOrder()) {
            return 2;
        } else if (order == n.getOrder()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -3;
        }
    }
}
```

then here comes the main method

```
Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>(Norwich::compareOrder);
norwichYxj.addItem(new Norwich(9));
norwichYxj.addItem(new Norwich(1));
System.out.println(norwichYxj.sort());
```

so what I'm interested in is that, why does not the method `compareOrder` keep the same parameters as the `compare` in `Comparator` but it can still work correctly?

Comment: your `compareOrder(Norwich n)` actually requires 2 values of type `Norwich` when executed: the parameter `n` and and an instance of `Norwich` to run this method on, because `compareOrder` is not static. So `Norwich::compareOrder` actually matches the `BiFunction` interface, just like `Comparator::compare`. I am sure this magic has some specific name in the JSR, but I don't know it.

Comment: Mr f1sh, I got the answer, since jdk1.8, like you said, because ```compareOrder``` is not static and the ```compare``` has a type of Norwich as its first parameter (after I pass ```Norwich``` to its wildcard), so the machine or the governer of Java :) will finally pass the instance on which the ```compareOrder``` run to the first parameter of ```compare```. \ The format must be ```ClassName::non-static method```, and the abstract method in functional interface keeps a first parameter of the same type as ```ClassName```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. You have passed through the constructor your implementation of the Comparator to be used for comparing.

```
Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>(Norwich::compareOrder);
```

Remember `Comparator` is nothing else than an interface. Since it is a functional interface, it can be represented through a lambda expression or a
method reference (as you did). The way you can pass the `Comparator` in the full form is as follows. Note the usage of the `compareOrder` method:

```
Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>(new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Norwich o1, Norwich o2) {
        return o1.compareOrder(o2);                      // usage of compareOrder
    }
});
```

This can be shortened to a lambda expression:

```
Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>((o1, o2) -> o1.compareOrder(o2));
```

It can be shortened again to a method reference:

```
Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>(Norwich::compareOrder);
```

Now you can see it can be represented in this way though the method `compareOrder` accepts only one formal parameter. The first parameter of the `Comparator#compare` method is the one invoking the `compareOrder` method and the second parameter is the one being passed to the `compareOrder` method.

Learn more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

---

Additionally, the classes you have constructed look a bit odd. Though the other answer doesn't in fact answer your question, it can lead you to a better code: [Implementing a functional interface via method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063639/implementing-a-functional-interface-via-method-reference/73064162#73064162)

Comment: That makes perfect sense.   And thx for the Additionally part :)

Comment: You are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

### class Yxj

1. The paramter T of your class Yxj should have more restrictions if you want to compare/sort in this class with T then say T must be comparable.
2. If your T array grows then don't implement your own growing array but use ArrayList instead which does that for you
3. If you do the first you don't need the Comperator anymore
4. Your methode sort only sorts the first and second element  so you will get problems. If the data is shorter you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if it is longer it won't sort the rest of elements. So with a Collection you could simple use Collections.sort(data);

   ```
   public class Yxj<T extends Comparable<T>> {

       private final List<T> data;

       public Yxj() {
           this.data = new ArrayList<>();
       }

       public void addItem(T t){
           data.add(t);
       }

       public void sort(){
           Collections.sort(data);
       }

       public  List<T> getData(){
           return data;
       }

       public void print(){
           System.out.println(data);
       }
   }
   ```

### class Norwich

If you done the above know your Norwich class must implement the Comparable interface so you can compare Norwich instances with the methode compareTo which also will be called each time you or the API ask directly or indirectly to compare to Norwich instances like for sorting ect.

```
public class Norwich implements Comparable<Norwich> {
    private int order;

    public Norwich(int o) {
        this.order = o;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Norwich other) {
        return this.order - other.order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Norwich{" +
                "order=" + order +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### Main

Done? Perfect, then your main could be looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Yxj<Norwich> norwichYxj = new Yxj<>();
    norwichYxj.addItem(new Norwich(9));
    norwichYxj.addItem(new Norwich(1));
    norwichYxj.sort();
    norwichYxj.print();
}
```

Comment: Nonono, my question is not how to realize a sortable container Yxj. And all the error-prone codes you mentioned can be ignored because I just focus on the reason why the method ```compareOrder``` can still work with only one parameter while the ```compare``` in ```Comparator``` has two.  thx though.